# In GSuite, is it possible to define one policy for company owned devices and another policy for user owned devices

Tags: google-workspace

Use case is as follows: Users leveraging a company owned device should be prompted to install app policy profile A when logging into their GSuite account. Users on a user owned device should be prompted to leverage app profile policy B when logging into the GSuite account. It seems like there might be a path to do this for Android but iOS is not clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this configuration applies to users not devices. For users devices you can enable "work profile" and the configuration only takes effects when a work app is open.

But some small configuration apply only to company owned devices.